# Query returning a row with one column's max value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns, City and Population.
The goal of this query is to return the single row that has the City with the highest population.
I have virtually no experience with SQL Server or databases or queries, as i'm currently in my first programming class ever. This database is linked to a program I'm creating with C# and Visual Studio. I've tried a handful of things such as:

```
SELECT City, Population FROM dbo.[Table] WHERE Population = Max(Population)
```

or

```
SELECT City, Max(Population) FROM dbo.[Table]
```

or

```
SELECT City, Population FROM dbo.[Table] ORDER BY Population Desc
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.[Table]
```

I feel like the answer is simple but going over my head nonetheless.

```
SELECT Max(Population) FROM dbo.[Table]
```

^^^ With this i was able to return only the maximum population but I need the city to return with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with the middle approach:

```
SELECT TOP 1 City, Population
FROM dbo.[Table]
ORDER BY Population Desc;
```

If you want ties as well:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES City, Population
FROM dbo.[Table]
ORDER BY Population Desc;
```